# Spring Boot doesn't include special characters while injecting Map from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

I have a simple Spring Boot project that aims to read and convert data from `application.yml` and convert it to a Java `Map<String,String>`. In my project's business layer, I need to fill that map with email addresses as keys. The problem starts here. Spring (or Spring Boot) does not work as I wanted. It totally ignores `@` characters in key side but works properly in values side.

Here are some codes:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo-filter")
public class Bootstrap implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Setter
    private Map<String, String> barFilters;

    @Setter
    private Map<String, String> bazFilters;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        barFilters.forEach((key, value) -> log.info(key + " -> " + value));

        bazFilters.forEach((key, value) -> log.info(key + " -> " + value));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
foo-filter:
  bar-filters:
    filtered1@mail.com: all
    filtered2@mail.com: all
    filtered3@mail.com: some
    filtered4@mail.com: none

  baz-filters:
    filtered1: all@mail.com
    filtered2: none@mail.com
```

And finally, this is the console output:

```
filtered1mail.com -> all
filtered2mail.com -> all
filtered3mail.com -> some
filtered4mail.com -> none
filtered1 -> all@mail.com
filtered2 -> none@mail.com
```

The first Map (`barFilters`) keys doesn't include `@` characters. Another things I tried:

-> to add double quotes (`"`) both sides.

-> to use @ with escape character (`\@`).

-> to use Unicode equivalent of @ (`U+0040`).

-> to use Escape sequence equivalent of @ (`\u0040`).

-> to use HTML code equivalent of @ (`&#64;`).

None of them have worked.

Why this happens and how can I solve this? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @DavidFlorez still same..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13404#issuecomment-395307439), you have to use

```
foo-filter:
  bar-filters:
    "[filtered1@mail.com]": all
    "[filtered2@mail.com]": all
    "[filtered3@mail.com]": some
    "[filtered4@mail.com]": none

  baz-filters:
    filtered1: all@mail.com
    filtered2: none@mail.com
```